# Not receiving data from NRF24L01

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I'm trying to send data from one Arduino board to another using **NRF24L01** connect to the two ends of the two Arduino boards. The **Tx** blinks in the transmitting end(Arduino board 1) but the receiving end(Arduino board 2) is not getting any value from it. Here is my code.

Transmitting end (Arduino board 1)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

RF24 myRadio(0, 1);
byte addresses[][6] = {"0"};

struct package
{
    int id = 1;
    float longitude = 0.0;
    float latitude = 0.0;
    char text[100] = "Geographic coordinates";
};

typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    myRadio.begin();
    myRadio.setChannel(115);
    myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    myRadio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    myRadio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    myRadio.write(&data, sizeof(data));

    Serial.print("\nPackage:");
    Serial.print(data.id);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.println(data.longitude);
    Serial.println(data.latitude);
    Serial.println(data.text);
    data.id = data.id + 1;
    data.longitude = data.longitude + 0.1;
    data.latitude = data.latitude + 0.1;
    delay(1000);
}
```

Receiving end (Arduino board 2)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

RF24 myRadio(7, 8);
struct package
{
    int id = 0;
    float longitude = 0.0;
    float latitude = 0.0;
    char text[100] = "empty";
};

byte addresses[][6] = {"0"};

typedef struct package Package;
Package data;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    myRadio.begin();
    myRadio.setChannel(115);
    myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    myRadio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
    myRadio.startListening();
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{

    if (myRadio.available())
    {
       while (myRadio.available())
       {
           myRadio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
       }
        Serial.print("\nPackage:");
        Serial.print(data.id);
        Serial.print("\n");
        Serial.println(data.longitude);
        Serial.println(data.latitude);
        Serial.println(data.text);
    }

}
```

This is how i connected the Arduino and NRF24L01
[image]

Any reason why im not getting the the data from the transmitting end?

Comment: try `myRadio.readBytes(&data, sizeof(data));` What nRF24 library you use?

Comment: @Juraj RF24.h by TMRh20

Comment: it doesn't implement Stream so it doesn't have readBytes

Comment: @Juraj you mean like myRadio.available() >= sizeof(data) ?

Comment: it will not work. I deleted the comment. the struct is bigger then the receive buffer

Comment: it can transfer only 32 bytes payload. send and receive the data in 32 byte parts

Comment: So should i change the struct?. This worked few weeks ago and now it is not. i bought new Arduino and NRF24 module still no luck :(

Comment: with the same library and this struct? perhaps it worked, but it didn't transfer the whole char array

Comment: change `while (myRadio.available())` to `if (myRadio.available())`

Answer (score 2):

Check the reading and writing pipe addresses.

First, the default is `0xE7E7E7E7E7` for pipe 0 (RX_ADDR_P0) and `0xC2C2C2C2C2` for pipe 1 (RX_ADDR_P1), see the [data sheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf).  Check that the transmitter (TX) address is the same as the receiver
(RX) pipe address.

Secondly, you should not set the pipe address to `0x0` even if that's common between the TX and RX.  This note comes from the data sheet:

> Addresses where the level shifts only one time (that is, 000FFFFFFF) can often be detected in
>   noise and can give a false detection, which may give a raised Packet Error Rate. Addresses
>   as a continuation of the preamble (hi-low toggling) also raises the Packet Error Rate

Comment: Actually the pipe address is "0" which is a string with implicit null terminator, which corresponds to 30 00 - which is still as bad. Also I don't know how the library fills up the missing 3 bytes from the address. In any case not knowing the real address can be troublesome. Better try something like "Link1" or something with 5 characters.